# How to return user back to my app after they navigate to a third party website like Gmail

Tags: javascript, iframe, gmail, single-page-application

I want to run my app in a single app mode, but give the user the ability to navigate to a few websites of my choosing such as Gmail. I run into this issue when I try to add gmail into my app:

```
chromewebdata/:1 Refused to display 'https://mail.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

From what I understand it won't let me add the iframe for secuity purposes and there isn't much I can do to get around it. I can however just add a widget that links to gmail external website from my app, but the issue I'm running into is how do I give the user a way to get back to my app from there? It's a tablet app and the back button on chrome isn't an option. When testing, I have to just relaunch the app to get back to it. Looking for any workarounds people may have found in similar cases.

I tried adding gmail in an iframe with the back button available, but then gmail doesn't load and I get the 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin' error.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, unfortunately. At least not for a random app. The scenario you are describing is what is going on between my bus ticket app and my mobile pay app. When I purchase a ticket I can choose to pay with MobilePay, then my bus ride app is redirecting me to MobilePay, I do the payment and I get redirected back into my bus ride app. But it is not the bus ride app (your app, in your case) that returned me back, it is the MobilePay app that knows that after a payment it should return control back to the main app that invoked it. It is the same way authentication with Facebook or Google works, there's a callback URL.

So no, unfortunately you cannot achieve this with Gmail because you don't control Gmail source code.

Comment: I mean, you could send them an email with a link back to the app :D